# extend functionality of php array parameter function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, string

Let's say I have a function that given an array it returns a piece of code like

```
//the array
$arr = array("EAL"   => "Eal",
         "CAZO"  => "Cazo",
         "COS"   => "Cos"           
        );

$result = '';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $result .= ' $("'.$key.'").click(function() { '
        . '        $("'.$value.'").fadeToggle();'
        . '  });'  
}
$result .= ' ; ';
```

which would look like

```
$result=' $("#EAL").click(function() { '
      . '   $("#Eal").fadeToggle();'
      . '    });'
      . ' $("#CAZO").click(function() { '
      . '   $("#Cazo").fadeToggle();'
      . '    });'
      . ' $("#COS").click(function() { '
      . '   $("#Cos").fadeToggle();'
      . '    });'  ;
```

Now how can I accomplish the case when I have multiple values for one key like:

```
$("#CAZO").click(function() { 
   $("#Cazo_x").fadeToggle();
   $("#Cazo_y").fadeToggle();
   $("#Cazo_z").fadeToggle();
});
```

so final result would be

```
$result=' $("#EAL").click(function() { '
      . '   $("#Eal").fadeToggle();'
      . '    });'
      . ' $("#CAZO").click(function() { '
      . '   $("#Cazo_x").fadeToggle();'
      . '   $("#Cazo_y").fadeToggle();'
      . '   $("#Cazo_z").fadeToggle();'
      . '    });'
      . ' $("#COS").click(function() { '
      . '   $("#Cos").fadeToggle();'
      . '    });'  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class to avoid all that duplicate code. Then you can do:

```
$(".fadeThis").on('click', function(){

  // the ID of the element is available as this.id
  $(this).fadeToggle();      

  // $(this).children() to get the children...

});
```

Comment: could you please give an example of using it on the code?

Comment: Sure, but how does the HTML mark-up look like? And point the elements you want to `fadeToggle`

Comment: I have input fields like http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UpX3L/1/

Comment: see: http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/143/

Comment: your answer is excellent, however how can I show/hide 2 or more divs if I click one link?

Comment: Then use a class for the DIVs below, that matches the ID + info:  http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/144/

Comment: Thank you, I would never thinh about using this solution

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = [
    'EAL'  => 'Eal',
    'CAZO' => [
        'Cazo_x',
        'Cazo_y',
        'Cazo_z'
    ],
    'COS'  => 'Cos'           
];

$result = '';
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $result .= '$("'.$key.'").click(function() {';
    if(!is_array($value)) { $value = [$value]; }
    foreach($value as $v) {
        $result .= '$("'.$v.'").fadeToggle();'
    }
    $result .= '});';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
//the array
$arr = array("EAL"   => "Eal",
     "CAZO"  => "Cazo",
     "COS"   => "Cos","key2" =>array("value1","value2")          
    );

$result = '';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
$result .= ' $("'.$key.'").click(function() { ';
    if( is_array( $value )){
        foreach( $value as $val )
        {
           $result .='        $("'.$val.'").fadeToggle();'
        }
    }else{
      $result .= '        $("'.$value.'").fadeToggle();'

    }
    $result .= '  });'  
}
$result .= ' ; ';
```